# Python - how to remove unbalanced parentheses and quotation marks

Tags: python, parentheses

I am cleaning a dataset which contains many typos, for example I found unbalanced parenthesis like these (the dataset is in French, sorry):

- `OXYDE D') HYDRAT`  (which should be `OXYDE D'HYDRAT`)
- `PEROXYDE DE) HYDRAT` (which should be `PEROXYDE DE HYDRAT`)
- `POUDRE DE) (PORCINE PANCRÉAS` (which should be `POUDRE DE PORCINE PANCRÉAS`)

Also I get double spaces between words from time to time which need to be replaced.

I have set a dictionary with the word or expression to be replaced and the corresponding replacement. But it won't take unbalanced parentheses or double spaces.

```
rep_dict = dict([('ABCD', 'ABCDE'), ('ABCDE FG', 'ABC DE FG')])
df.replace(rep_dict, regex=True)
```

unbalanced parenthesis at position xxx

Comment: That seems very strange. Could you please show more about how your dataframe is structured and could you add the full error stacktrace?

Comment: Also: why are you using `regex=True`? The examples you show do not need regex. Or is your real data more complex?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Also post your problem code; we can't fix what you haven't posted.  If you haven't written any code yet, then you have an issue for research, not Stack Overflow.